# Does the stellar MK classification fix the apparent luminosity?

Tags: astrophysics

### Introduction

Let say we have some stars and their spectral classification in the MK index. (not all HD stars)

- HD xxxx - B3
- HD yyyy - O7
- HD zzzz - F0
- ....

If the stars share the same spectral type, then **they share the same superficial temperature** $T$. Also, the $LRT$ relation holds

$$\boxed{L=4\pi \sigma R^2 T^4} $$

for $L$ absolute luminosity, $\sigma$ the [Stefan-Boltzmann constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_constant) and $R$ the stellar radius. By definition of $L$

$$L=\ell 4\pi r^2$$

where $\ell$ is the apparent luminosity and $r$ is the distance of the star from the Earth. Let's take a look at the distance

$$r^2=\frac{L}{\ell 4 \pi}=\frac{4\pi \sigma R^2T^4}{\ell 4 \pi}=\frac{\sigma R^2 T^4}{\ell}$$

### Question

Do I need further information to say anything about the **distance** and the **apparent magnitude** of the stars, in the form of their stellar radius $R$ and the apparent luminosity $\ell$.

Comment: Haven't you already answered your own question? Are you just asking for confirmation that your answer is correct?

Comment: I'm asking for confirmation - further comments about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, your relation among $r$, $R$, $T$, and $\ell$ holds. Knowing any three can determine the fourth.

That said, I've never seen "apparent luminosity" defined like that, where it doesn't have the same units as luminosity. Really I've never seen "apparent luminosity" defined. In fact, the [*flux*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiative_flux) matches that definition:
$$ F = \frac{L}{4\pi r^2}. $$
Then your relation could be written
$$ r^2 = \frac{\sigma R^2T^4}{F}. $$
$F$ is measured from photometry and $T$ is measured from spectroscopy. $R$ can be determined from the spectrum with stellar modeling, but those models are calibrated on stars with known values of $r$ obtained from parallax.

Comment: Apparent luminosity is a different name for flux. Yes, it's somewhat a misnomer, like many other things in astronomy :-)